# Find lone peak with high sampling cost

Tags: optimization, noise

<sup>(I'm not sure if this is the correct stackexchange place to ask; please redirect me if it doesn't belong here.)</sup>

I have a 2D function `f(x,y)` which is (near-)zero everywhere, except for a single region where there is a gaussian peak of "width" `0.15mm` (created by a normal gaussian + noise). The image below shows this, all red dots are background noise, the peak is centered.
[image: noise+gaussian, all red dots are background noise]

The problem is, there's a high cost for sampling `f(x,y)`. If there was no noise, no problem, estimate the gradient and off you go. But with noise this technique will just get me to random locations.

I can manually narrow the region of interest down to an area of 4x4mm, but that'll still take me around 274 samples (based on circle covering problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716460/fully-cover-a-rectangle-with-minimum-amount-of-fixed-radius-circles)) to catch at least a glimpse of the edge of the gaussian.

Are there any techniques for this kind of problem? I'm thinking towards optimal sampling location/sampling sequence? Ie spiralling out from the center; hexagonal grid; start coarse, then finetune...

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think either our site or [the statistics site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) may be able to help you. I don't know this stuff, but taking averages will tend to cancel (additive) noise, so there are probably known methods for detecting a positive gradient if you estimate it using more points. Of course, the gradient of a gaussian drops off very fast, so the signal-to-noise ratio becomes unmanageably low fairly soon.